# CSS <div> Style Shorter than Child Element

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm working on a project to better my knowledge of Spring MVC practices. To do this, I've been creating a very scaled down version of Twitter. Basically, a user can sign in and post a little blurb and also see a timeline of their previous blurbs and all their follower's blurbs.

I have a background image across the whole page and a container in the middle with a light blue background for just the post blurb box and the timeline. The light blue background only goes to the bottom of the visible page. If the timeline goes down past a single page view where you have to scroll down, the light blue background stops at the bottom of what was visible on the initial load.

I have my page defined like this: 
The div class=blurb is the blurbs in the timeline.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainPanel">
        <div id="timeline">
                <div class="class="blurb"">
                    <span class="user">test</span> <span
                        class="displayName">Test User</span> <span class="bodytext">This is a small blurb.</span>
                    <span class="timestamp">1 hours ago</span>
                </div>

                <div class="blurb">
                    <span class="user">admin</span> <span
                        class="displayName">Test admin</span> <span class="bodytext">This is another small blurb.</span>
                    <span class="timestamp">1 hours ago</span>
                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS style for the container is shown below.

```
#container {
    width: 650px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #DDEEF6;
}
```

Can I modify that container CSS in a way to make it be as long as the timeline is? The timeline grows with every blurb post.

Screenshot with height defined to 100%
[image: Height defined to 100% in container styling]

Screenshot with height undefined
[image: Height left undefined in container styling]

**UPDATE:**
Okay, so it absolutely has to do with the floats. Thanks to the two commenters below. The #socialPanel is defined as such:

```
#socialPanel {
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
```

Using Chrome's developer tools, if I clear the float is drops the social panel below my blurbs/tweets and moves the light blue background all the way down the list of blurbs.

Any suggestions on what I could research to keep the socialPanel floating left at the top, but still have my light blue background use all the available height? Many thanks on helping me figure it out this far!

**UPDATE TWO:**

I combined the methods shown in the answer below to solve my problem. I added a div with class clearer with `clear:both;` and then removed the `height: 100%;` from the #container styling. This resolved the problem.

**NOTE:**
Adding the `overflow: hidden;` to my container's styling made the page cut off after the light blue area, it did not make the light blue area go all the way down.

Many thanks to all the help! I'm still learning and it was all very appreciated!!

Comment: Where's the CSS for the divs inside the panel? You may just need to clear floats

Comment: This probably has more to do with the CSS of the #mainPanel and #socialPanel. If these internal divs are floated or absolutely positioned then their height is not used to calculate the height of the containing block.

Comment: The mainPanel is floated left and the socialPanel is floated right. So that's what's causing my height to fail? I originally left out those CSS styles, I really didn't think they were relevant. I'll try removing those floats.

Comment: @Kyle Yes. That's your problem. Removing the floats will probably cause other problems (or why use them in the first palce).  You might be able to only remove the float from the "longer" of the two divs (probably #mainPanel) and then set a min-height on that div so it's never shorter than #socialPanel.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect my attempts after your suggestions. If one of you will post a similar response as an answer I'll mark it correct. Many thanks for the help, I've been scratching my head for awhile with this. I didn't realize floats could cause that problem, I'll try to find some more research materials online about using floats properly.

Comment: @Kyle My answer has a nice example showing a simple broken example and how to fix it http://jsfiddle.net/c3vTU/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to add a clearing div after your two inner divs. http://jsfiddle.net/c3vTU/1/

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-left"> Stuff on the left</div>
  <div class="inner-right">Stuff on the right <br/><br/></div>    
  <div class="clearer"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    width: 520px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.inner-left {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

.inner-right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.clearer {
      clear: both;
```

}

As @MichaelIrigoyen noted, you can also just add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow:auto` (I think makes more sense) to your container. http://jsfiddle.net/c3vTU/4/ This is cleaner and I love it!

Comment: I have tried the overflow: hidden technique and the div-clear technique. Neither of which work when running the website in Chrome or Firefox on my computer. Completely flustered, I copied the view-source contents and my css file contents to a jsfiddle and BOTH the div-clear and overflow methods work on jsfiddle, any ideas as to why  this fails on my Mac? I'm hosting through tomcat 7 and I cleared Chrome's cache.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YFxc6/ This is my jsfiddle where it's working. This one has the overflow and clear div in place. Either could be quickly commented out.

Comment: @Kyle So you don't have it working yet? Maybe give us a link to a server where it doesn't work?

Comment: I did get it working using your technique and @Set Sail Media's technique. I updated the Question to show the resolution. It works when I have the `<div class="clearer"></div>` and I remove the `#container`'s `height: 100%;` element. When I use the `overflow: hidden;` it just chops off my page where I can't scroll down. When I use only one of the two methods listed above it gets the initial results, but together it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Place `overflow:hidden` on the `#container`.

**How does it work?**

One would think placing this style on a container would hide the floats instead of containing them. What actually happens is that `overflow:hidden` makes the element establish a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). This fixes the float containment of any children floating within it. This CSS fix is more practical then including an additional element in the HTML styled with `clear:both` and works on all modern browsers, including IE7+.

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/c3vTU/3/ Can you explain why so I can upvote it? The logic seems backwards in my head

Comment: `overflow:auto` also works http://jsfiddle.net/c3vTU/4/   Here's an explanation http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/ Note that this behavior is not yet specified, but does work in later browsers

Comment: It is specified behavior, take a look at the BFC in the Visual formatting model by the W3C.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply remove the height declaration (`height: 100%;`) from `#container`, it will expand as its children do (and the background of course, too).

Comment: I added screenshots to the original question after trying your suggestion. I tried to take the screenshots where you could see the developer tab in chrome. Removing the height definition just makes it a little blue line at the top. I don't know if it matters, but this is a separate css file being used by a jsp page rendered by tomcat 7.

Comment: It would, if the children weren't floating and not being cleared

Comment: Why the downvote? This works without floated children (OP's question had no mention of floats...)

Comment: "UPDATE: Okay, so it absolutely has to do with the floats."